# Gains in running a docker container on the same OS type?

Tags: docker

Are there significant gains in running a docker container based on a certain OS, on the same OS type and version?! For example, running a container based on a certain version of Ubuntu, on an Ubuntu server (of the same version), v.s. a Debian/CentOS/CoreOS server?

Notwithstanding, that upgrading the servers' and containers' OS in lockstep, might not be how ops always tend to go on in reality.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be.

Docker and other linux container technologies share access to the kernel and have their own, entirely separate filesystems from the host. Therefore, running an arbitrary container on the same hardware and kernel but two different distros should not in theory make any difference. That is what makes containers so powerful, they are reliably identical across a wide variety of hosts.

Comment: For different OSes between the container and the host there is no difference, but there is a memory advantage in running many containers from the same image (or with many layers in common), with AUFS. Then shared libraries pages will be reused across containers and if you start having hundreds of Apache containers that could become noticeable.
Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-dev/NOeA2YHl1sU